# CSS selector to hide elements nested

Tags: css

I need to hide all but the first one h3 in a list of containers. They only contain classes.

```
<div class="preview">
    --content
</div>
<div class="preview evaluation">
    <h3>Heading</h3>  <!-- should stay -->
</div>
<div class="preview evaluation">
    <h3>Heading</h3>   <!-- should hide -->
</div>
<div class="preview evaluation">
    <h3>Heading</h3>    <!-- should hide -->
</div>
```

I need to do this only with css.

Comment: `.evaluation h3 { display: none; }` should do the trick...

Comment: @RaphaelMüller It may or may not (depending on if the containers have other elements and if the first `h3` is always inside `.preview`).

Comment: @RaphaelMüller: Still it may not depending on what other elements are there and how the classes are assigned. More info needs to be added to the question in my opinion.

Comment: @Harry you are completely right, but the solution is a possible solution to the given example

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. As the comments show, you haven't fully explained all the possible situations that would affect the outcome.

Comment: there was an error on the markup fixed

Comment: @ManuelValle: Will the first `h3` always be inside the first element with class `evaluation`? Will the first element with `evaluation` class be the 2nd element inside its container. I am not trying to be cynical but there are still some missing information.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. There is no *"nth-of-class"* selector.

Comment: @Paulie_D: For this very structure in question `.evaluation ~ .evaluation > h3 {display: none}` would work but I am still unclear on the various possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer according to the edited question...**

If you want to hide only the `<h3>` elements, then:

```
.evaluation>h3 { display: none; }
.evaluation:nth-of-type(2)>h3 { display: block; }
```

If you want to hide the `<div>` elements containing `<h3>` elements, then:

```
.evaluation { display: none; }
.evaluation:nth-of-type(2) { display: block; }
```

**Alternatively you can do...**

```
.evaluation:not(:nth-of-type(2))>h3 { display: none; }
```

**or...**

```
.evaluation:not(:nth-of-type(2)) { display: none; }
```

Comment: No, I want to keep the first h3, but hide the other ones. So far the answers given hide all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to have the structure in your example:

```
.evaluation + .evaluation h3 {display:none}
```

Comment: But you need to provide all possible configurations, if you need it to work for anything else.